# Powershell Instance Parameter

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am automating the creation of user accounts in our Windows AD. I am trying to copy the permissions from one account to another,(like you would if you right click and copied a user inside of the "Active Directory Users and Computers" application) but when using the cmdlet 'New AD-User' and passing in a variable to the 'instance' parameter, it does nothing different than if I do not pass the variable at all.

This is what I am using to obtain the `$userInstance` variable:

```
$userInstance = Get-ADUser -Identity $department User
```

This is the code I am using to create a new user:

```
New-ADUser `
         -SamAccountName $userName `
         -UserPrincipalName "$userName@123.COM" `
         -Name "$firstName $lastName" `
         -GivenName $firstName `
         -Surname $lastName `
         -Enabled $true `
         -DisplayName "$firstName $lastName" `
         -City $city `
         -PostalCode $zip `
         -Company $company `
         -State $state `
         -EmailAddress $email `
         -Department $department `
         -Instance $userInstance `
         -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString "1234" -AsPlainText -Force)
```

When I run this command, it does the same exact thing as if I ran this command without the instance parameter.

```
New-ADUser `
         -SamAccountName $userName `
         -UserPrincipalName "$userName@123.COM" `
         -Name "$firstName $lastName" `
         -GivenName $firstName `
         -Surname $lastName `
         -Enabled $true `
         -DisplayName "$firstName $lastName" `
         -City $city `
         -PostalCode $zip `
         -Company $company `
         -State $state `
         -EmailAddress $email `
         -Department $department `
         -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString "1234" -AsPlainText -Force)
```

Am I missing something? I do not understand what the 'instance' parameter is supposed to be doing if it only copies certain attributes that are easily obtainable(state, company, city). Is there something out there that actually copies a template account or do I need to write a loop that goes through every single attribute, permission, and group in the template account that provides some sort of meaning to my organization and assign them manually?

Comment: How did you populate the variable `$userInstance`? Usuall you use `Get-AdUser` for the user you want to copy and save the output in a variable ...

Comment: Please add this to your question - not as comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Permissions" might not have been the word I was looking for necessarily. I wanted to create the user and assign them the same groups and directory location as a previous User. I was able to add group membership to my new users by using the method stated by @Oliver Hauck earlier

```
Add-ADGroupMember
```

This aided me in my findings, but what I desired was to not have to write long, repetitive switch code for each new employee type, along with their groups, we could onboard. In hopes that someone sees this and doesn't feel intrigued in writing super long, boring switch code, I wanted to share how I achieved this if it helps anyone else in the future. I still obtained the *$userInstance* variable in the same way, but adding the *-Property* parameter defined to *MemberOf*

```
$userInstance = Get-ADUser -Identity $department User -Properties MemberOf
```

I then used the *$userInstance* variable to obtain the properties I needed from it (Groups to copy, Directory Path)

```
//Obtains the Path from the copied User, without their common name (CN) attached
$path = $userInstance.DistinguishedName.split(",",2)[-1]
```

I still created the new user with the same command as above but added the *-Path* parameter to assign the directory path to the *New-ADUser* cmd

```
New-ADUser `
     -SamAccountName $userName `
     -UserPrincipalName "$userName@123.COM" `
     -Name "$firstName $lastName" `
     -GivenName $firstName `
     -Surname $lastName `
     -Enabled $true `
     -DisplayName "$firstName $lastName" `
     -City $city `
     -PostalCode $zip `
     -Company $company `
     -State $state `
     -Path $path `
     -EmailAddress $email `
     -Department $department `
     -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString "1234" -AsPlainText -Force)
```

And here is how I obtained and assigned the Group Membership to the New User

```
//Obtains the groups to be copied from the existing User
$refGroups = $userInstance.MemberOf
//Adds AD Group Membership to User
$refGroups | Add-ADGroupMember -Members $userName
```

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you mean by "permission"?

Permissions on resources are set based on the objectSid of a user. Since this is unique to every user you can never "copy" them (and related permissions) to a new user.

Group memberships are stored on groups not on users. The memberOf attribute is just a "backLink" so this won't be copied neither.

Group membership needs to be added in a separate step, e.g. by using

```
Add-ADGroupMember
```

cmdlet in PowerShell...

Comment: By "permission" I mean the group memberships, where the user is located in the AD, things of that nature. Based on your answer and some other research, there is a lot that goes into "copying" a user if you really want to replicate all of the functionality or "permissions" the previous account had, programmatically.